# IFERROR Vlookup outputs 0, How to avoid this

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AS:AS,'Data'!B:G,6,FALSE),"")
```

This formula outputs value 0 when there is no item to vlookup in column AS:AS, How do I avoid the 0, to output only blank?

Comment: The first parameter to `VLOOKUP` should surely be a single cell, not a range? But either way, if the value in `AS1` is not in `DATA!B:B` then it will return `#N/A`, not `0`

Comment: @Dan A range works very well indeed.

Comment: Actually when the cell in AS is truly blank (hit delete button) you'll get `#N/A` not zero. There must be a zero length string `=""` or a space in the cell which then causes a match to a blank cell; hence the zero value.

Comment: @D_Bester I tried with `=""` and it still gives me `#N/A`.

Comment: @Dan Cell A1 = "", B1 = "", C1 is blank, `=VLOOKUP(A1,B1:C1,2,FALSE)` shows 0.

Comment: @D_Bester oh I misread the question, I thought OP meant when the value in `AS` isn't in the lookup range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing in NA if the cell value be missing:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(AS:AS="",NA(),AS:AS),'Data'!B:G,6,FALSE),"")
```

The idea here is that empty cells would pass `#N/A` to `VLOOKUP` thereby causing an error, and causing the error message to print (in your case you have chosen empty string).

Comment: @D_Bester I know little of VBA.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

A formula will always output 0 from a blank cell.
You can fix it by:

1. Use cell formatting such as `0;-0;;@`
2. Use `=T(...)` if you're expecting text

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use a single cell as a lookup value and the specific range for your lookup array so that there's no possibility of the formula returning zero unless that's a valid result from your table, e.g. in row 2 copied down if required

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AS2,'Data'!B$2:G$100,6,FALSE),"")`